# RVM default ruby and rails gem path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I'm a relatively new linux and rails dev and I'm attempting the following setup:
Debian 6 / Rails 3.1.3 / Ruby 1.9.3

**FYI:**

1. My system is currently configured with Ruby 1.8.7...which is still installed and running
2. I have rails websites up and running on a Linode vhost apache2 setup

**Following instructions here > https://rvm.io/rvm/install/ I did the following:**

1. List item
2. I installed RVM
3. I reloaded my shell environment (btw I think Debian is $ source /etc/profile)
4. I installed Ruby 1.9.3
5. Run RVM use 1.9.3 --default
6. Added...echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bashrc...to my bash script (I also tried .profile)
7. Installed rails, gems etc

All seems well. When I run $ Ruby -v  and it reads correctly. When I run gem list, all is good there too. When I run RVM list, it shows my versions and lists 1.9.3 as my default.

**Issues:**

1. List item
2. When I log out and log back in...if I run $ Ruby -v it shows version 1.8.7, not 1.9.3. So as far as my terminal goes, it's not automatically using my default version.
3. My rails app still uses the old gem path.

**Questions:**

1. What am I missing here? Every tutorial I look at never goes past these steps. Am I missing something basic?
2. How do i make my rails app use the ruby version controlled by RVM
3. How do I make Debian recognize my bash function automatically?
4. Can anybody give me or point me to a more in depth explanation on how this all fits together?

Comment: to use any version of ruby, in your case 1.9.3 `rvm use 1.9.3 --default` will do. It'll use the 1.9.3 version by default. For more help on rvm refer to http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/#explained

Comment: Thank Naveed, you'll notice in my step 5, I did just that. However, it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Debian my guess is you use gnome-terminal, it is known to not have enabled login shell by default: https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/

More details on what shell login is:

- https://rvm.io/support/faq/#shell_login

the document describes **current** state of shell login, this was not always like this and it was confused and misused / misunderstood for long time (and still is in few tools and by few developers)

Comment: Thanks mpapis, this does seem like the issue regarding my default rvm on login. Do you think this is the same issue with my rails environment as well?

Comment: Also...I think the answer for me here is...don't use RVM on the server. I don't "need" multiple versions...just was trying to do things right...however, after more reading, sounds like this is more configuration than I really care to deal with.

Comment: @user1221747 rvm behind the scenes uses environment files, it's enough to source that environment file on the server - and you are ready to go